# Use pg_dump with postgis extensions?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I'm using Postgres 9.4. I'm trying to dump a database (both the schema and the actual data) with the PostGIS extensions (set up using `CREATE EXTENSION`):

```
$ pg_dump prescribing -U prescribing -h localhost -Fc > prescribing.dump
Password:
```

But when I type in the db password, I see this:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE topology.topology IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

How can I dump this database?

UPDATE: it says these tables are owned by `postgres`:

```
 public | frontend_sha                               | table             | prescribing
 public | geography_columns                          | view              | postgres
 public | geometry_columns                           | view              | postgres
 public | pg_stat_statements                         | view              | postgres
 public | raster_columns                             | view              | postgres
 public | raster_overviews                           | view              | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys                            | table             | postgres
 public | vw_chemical_summary_by_ccg                 | materialized view | prescribing
```

Maybe I could just dump the other tables, and import them into another database set up in the same way? Or maybe I could run pg_dump as a superuser? But if I try `pg_dump prescribing` then it still asks me for a password, and I don't know what that should be.

Comment: The quick fix, as you say would be to "run pg_dump as a superuser": but that means doing `pg_dump -U postgres prescribing`, the `-U postgres` bit is important (unless your current shell user is postgres, or you specify $PGUSER, or something like that). The more involved fix will be to ensure that your `prescribing` user has appropriate privileges (SELECT, USAGE) on all schemas and tables in your `prescribing` database.

Comment: Thanks! `pg_dump -U postgres prescribing` still asks me for a password, and as far as I know the postgres user doesn't have a password, so that's confusing. However switching to the shell user postgres (`sudo su postgres`) fixed the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are using "peer" authentication in your pg_hba.conf file. That's fine, but if you want to learn more about how to configure authentication, see [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Answer (score -2):

What about using -T modifier for pg_dump to skip those tables?

For example -T topology.*

Comment: What does the -T modifier do?  How will it help?  Edit your answer and add little explanation and you may improve your credibility.